# Confine and Flex mode in Oracle Reports Builder

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

My boss said I have to edit some oracle reports.I have to move some fields to left and right.But every time I do that the layout is broken.I search in google and I found out that it has something to do with Confine and FLex mode.

How to use these properties? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right, when moving objects there're some restrictions managed by those buttons appear on the above part of `Report Editor`(*for `Paper Layout` or `Paper Design` modes* ).

The following buttons are used in *the design time* :

***Confine On :*** [image]

Whenever toggled, the child objects of a frame cannot be moved outside of that frame . (*To determine the parent frame just click on* [image] )

To set them as free use ***Confine Off :*** [image]

***Flex On :*** [image]

Whenever toggled, as the child object(s) of a frame are moved the parent frame expands or shrinks along with that object(s).

To block such a movement use ***Flex Off :*** [image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros for explaining. :D